# Word for a message that most people find plain but a smaller group see as supportive

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like there's an idiom for this, such as if someone makes a comment that might seem innocuous at face value so you dismiss it, but another group of people who are more extreme might see as a sign that the person is on their side.

Something like "Well, some people, criminals, who are coming into this country don't belong here." Where a racist or a white nationalist might think "He supports our vision of the pure race," but the rest of us would think "Yeah, I don't want criminals coming into our country".

I feel like it's similar to "false flag" or something, but I can't remember quite the right word.

An example sentence, in response to a statement by someone else to call them out on their ____-ing:

> What you're doing here is saying "This is Mexico's fault" but that's a ____ for people who don't think Mexicans belong here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you mean **[a dog whistle](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dog-whistle)**

> **dog whistle** *noun*
>
> (TO CALL DOG) a whistle used to train dogs, with a very high sound that humans cannot hear
>
> (POLITICS) (*disapproving*): a remark, speech, advertisement, etc. by a
>   politician that is intended to be understood by a particular group,
>   especially one with feelings of racism or hatred, without actually
>   expressing these feelings: *"Attacks on "political correctness" can be a
>   dog whistle to rally white voters."*

Answer (score 4):

A **shibboleth** is a word or term that is only used in a certain way by a certain group of people, and it enables these people to recognise a fellow member. Outsiders may not notice anything out of the ordinary, and/or they may be unable to properly use the term.

Some general, tangentially related terms are *sign, tell-tale, pejorative, dysphemism, discours*.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes referred to as ***coded*** [X] (where *X* is usually racism).

It's usually used by opponents of the speaker to imply the presence of the “dog whistle” ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a logical fallacy known as [**conflation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation).

> **Conflation** happens when the identities of two or more individuals, concepts, or places, sharing some characteristics of one another, seem to be a single identity, and the differences appear to become lost.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation) In logic, it is the practice of treating two distinct concepts as if they were one, which produces errors or misunderstandings as a fusion of distinct subjects tends to obscure analysis of relationships which are emphasized by contrasts.
>
> Conflation in logical terms is very similar to, if not identical to, [**equivocation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation).

(Source: Wikipedia.) You said:

> Something like "Well, some people, criminals, who are coming into this country don't belong here.". Where a racist or a white nationalist might think "He supports our vision of the pure race" but the rest of us would think "Yeah I don't want criminals coming into our country".

In your example, the racist conflates the simple statement *Well, some people, criminals, who are coming into this country don't belong here."* with their own extreme beliefs; hence they incorrectly assume that the speaker is in agreement with them.

Whereas the more level-headed listener takes the statement at face value, without combining it with any extraneous, irrelevant meanings.